# Trouble with conditional hovering - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to build a tic-tac-toe board that changes colors based on a player's selection. That part works, but when trying to add a hover preview function for the player's potential choice, I'm having trouble getting the correct outcome.

In essence, player 1 will have yellow tiles, and player 2's will be blue. Right now, the hover feature is causing all tiles clicked to be blue, and while it hovers over blank tiles correctly, already it inverts the color for tiles already selected.

Any idea what's going on?

relevant jQuery:

```
count = 0
// hover classes for clear selection
$( "td" ).hover(function() {
if (count % 2 === 0) {
    $(this).toggleClass('yellowHover');
    return;
    } else {
    $(this).toggleClass('blueHover');
    return;
    };
});

// upon click change turns, countt++, change box value, check if winner
$('td').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    var col = $(this).index();

    if(player1Name=="" || player2Name==""){
  alert("Please set player all the names.");
  return;
}

    // doesn't allow spot to be clicked on twice
    if(board[row][col]!==0){
  alert("This position is taken. Please try again.");
  return;
};
    // if count is even, player 1 is yellow
    // if count is odd, player 2 is blue
    if (count % 2 === 0) {
        board[row][col] = 1;
        $(this).addClass('yellow');
        count++;
        winnerCheck(1, player1Name);
        draw();
        messageBoard(player2Name + "'s turn. Click a circle to mark it blue.");
    } else {
        board[row][col] = 2;
        $(this).addClass('blue');
        count++;
        winnerCheck(2, player2Name);
        draw();
        messageBoard(player1Name + "'s turn. Click a circle to mark it yellow.");
    };
});
```

relevant css:

```
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffc300;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #73d2c9;
}

.yellowHover {
  background-color: #ffc300;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.blueHover {
  background-color: #73d2c9;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

relevant html:

```
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="box_row" >
                    <td id="box_0_0" class="box_cell" data-row="0" data-col="0" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_0_1" class="box_cell" data-row="0" data-col="1" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_0_2" class="box_cell" data-row="0" data-col="2" data-clicked="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="box_row">
                    <td id="box_1_0" class="box_cell" data-row="1" data-col="0" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_1_1" class="box_cell" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_1_2" class="box_cell" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-clicked="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="box_row">
                    <td id="box_2_0" class="box_cell" data-row="2" data-col="0" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_2_1" class="box_cell" data-row="2" data-col="1" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_2_2" class="box_cell" data-row="2" data-col="2" data-clicked="0"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: What is the count variable? And where is your HTML? At least provide a description of what kind of structure you are using so we can duplicate your issue

Comment: @Larz sorry about that. just added relevant html. count is initialized at 0 and increases by 1 after each turn to keep track of whose turn it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you just make the blue and yellow classes a little more specific.

Instead of:

```
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffc300;
 }
.blue {
  background-color: #73d2c9;
 }
```

...try something like this:

```
td.box_cell.yellow {
   background-color: #ffc300;
}

td.box_cell.blue {
    background-color: #73d2c9;
}
```

Here's a simplified version of your code to demonstrate (hopefully) the result you're looking for:

```js
count = 0;

$("td").hover(function(){
  if (count % 2 === 0) {
    $(this).toggleClass('yellowHover');
    return;
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass('blueHover');
    return;
  }
});
$('td').click(function(e) {
  // if count is even, player 1 is yellow
  // if count is odd, player 2 is blue
    if (count % 2 === 0) {
      $(this).addClass('yellow');
       count++; 
       console.log(count);
    } else {        
        $(this).addClass('blue');
        count++;        
        console.log(count);
    }
  
});
```

```css
/* Added this for demo purposes only */
td {border:1px solid pink;width:50px;height:50px}
/* -- */

td.box_cell.yellow {
  background-color: #ffc300;
}

td.box_cell.blue {
  background-color: #73d2c9;
}

.yellowHover {
  background-color: #ffc300;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.blueHover {
  background-color: #73d2c9;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="box_row" >
                    <td id="box_0_0" class="box_cell" data-row="0" data-col="0" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_0_1" class="box_cell" data-row="0" data-col="1" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_0_2" class="box_cell" data-row="0" data-col="2" data-clicked="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="box_row">
                    <td id="box_1_0" class="box_cell" data-row="1" data-col="0" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_1_1" class="box_cell" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_1_2" class="box_cell" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-clicked="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="box_row">
                    <td id="box_2_0" class="box_cell" data-row="2" data-col="0" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_2_1" class="box_cell" data-row="2" data-col="1" data-clicked="0"></td>

                    <td id="box_2_2" class="box_cell" data-row="2" data-col="2" data-clicked="0"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Also - just a suggestion - you may want to clean up your code. I noticed some unnecessary semicolons after a few if statements in there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
td:hover{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

and remove the hover function--since all that the CSS is changing is the opacity for either td class (.blue or .yellow).

No javascript necessary :)

Comment: I get that, but I was hoping for this to be a preview of the color they'd turn the `td`. So, the background color at the time of hover is technically white.

Comment: ah, so you want the hover color to be either blue or yellow depending on whose turn it is?

Comment: well if, as you say, it hovers the unselected ones correctly, add a check to see if the td is already selected in the hover function... something like


$( "td" ).hover(function(e) {
if($(e.target).hasClass('blue') || $(e.target).hasClass('yellow')){return;}
if (count % 2 === 0) {...

Comment: Thanks, @Ted. I'll play around with that. Still can't figure out why each click is adding class "blue", but will figure it out.